# Good polynomials to use that can fit closed complex 2D shapes

Tags: geometry, polynomials, regression, spline

Are there any good polynomials that can be used to fit closed complex 2D shapes? For example, the silhouette of everyday objects or people. I am aware I can use a spline for example, however, they tend to over smooth the shape. Can anyone point me in the right direction/research that pertains to this problem?

Comment: Use discrete Fourier components in a radial representation.

Comment: [Smooth, easy to compute interpolating splines](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02187690)